# Create a external table using azure storage

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, storage

I am trying to create the table below using but i am receiving the error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user
>   [admin] does not have [ALL] privilege on
>   [wasb://mycontainer@smystg.blob.core.windows.net]

I already add the property with storage key to core-site.xml and also:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.secure.mode</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.cred.service.urls</name>
  <value>{URL}</value>
</property>
```

here is my hql:

```
Create external table test(
id int,
name string)
stored as ORC
location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystg.blob.core.windows.net';
Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely you need to update the azure blob storage permissions

"Containers > [container] > [blob]
In the Metadata section of Blob Properties, modify the key hdi_permission "owner" value to the user executing the Hive process."
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/185859/how-to-create-hive-table-with-azure-wasb-storage.html

Comment: Now my query keeps running and does not return an error.
Any ideas?